# Using COUNT with WHERE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

Having a bit of trouble.  I need to find all of the countries that have a common language.  I only need to list the countries in which the language happens more than once.  I'm having a bit of trouble with this code.

```
-- group countries by a common language
SELECT country, language
FROM countryinfo
HAVING COUNT(language) > 1
GROUP BY language
```

Comment: Also, since you are basically reducing your table to one row per `language`, you should use something like `GROUP_CONCAT(country)` to condense all the countries with that language into a string `Australia, UK, America` (e.g.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what I think you want, I think the clearest approach is to use a subquery; either this:

```
SELECT country, language
  FROM countryinfo
 WHERE language IN
        ( SELECT language
            FROM countryinfo
           GROUP BY language
          HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        )
;
```

or this:

```
SELECT country, language
  FROM countryinfo ci1
 WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM countryinfo ci2
           WHERE ci2.language = ci1.language
             AND ci2.country <> ci1.country
        )
;
```

Note that this gives a different result from other answers, because what I think you want is different from what other answerers think you want. You'll have to try these queries out and figure out which is what you meant.

---

**Edited to add:** here's an alternative theory about what you want:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(country),
       language
  FROM countryinfo
 GROUP BY language
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
;
```

Comment: Can you explain the COUNT(1)?  Thanks.

Comment: `COUNT` counts non-null values, so `COUNT(1)` just means "count all" (since `1` is, inherently never null). It's also often written as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Ok, so the first one is working, except I am unable to GROUP BY language with that one, I added the group by after the where, as well as before, and they both are not giving me what I am looking for, any ideas?

Comment: @stytown: I intended for those queries to be used without any modification whatsoever. If they're not giving you what you want, then the problem is that I've misunderstood what you want; and I can't help you until you help me understand. Why do you want to add an additional `GROUP BY language`? Do you not want a row for each country?

Comment: @stytown: I've edited my answer to give a different possibility; this is what 'mathematical.coffee', in his/her comment above, thinks you want.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting.  It wasn't really what I had in mind, but that seems like a better way of going about it.  What I had in mind, for example, was for it to list each country, with the language that country uses next to it.  Instead it was only listing one country for each language.  So, instead of listing both Syria and Egypt, which both use Arabic, it would only list Egypt for some reason, that was where my problem laid.  Thanks.

Comment: @stytown: My original queries *do* list each country. What may have confused you is that those queries didn't specify an `ORDER BY`, so Egypt and Syria wouldn't necessarily be next to each other in the list. (You can add `ORDER BY language, country` to the end of either of those queries to all the countries sorted by language and name.) Alternatively, what may have confused you is that you added a `GROUP BY language` where it didn't belong. In that case, the solution would be to remove the `GROUP BY language`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's in the positioning. This should work.

```
-- group countries by a common language
SELECT country, language
FROM countryinfo
GROUP BY language
HAVING COUNT(language) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but it's only listing one country for each common language, I am trying to list all of the countries that share a common language.

Answer (score 1):

If you group by `language`, then you need to count `countries`.

```
SELECT country, language
FROM countryinfo
GROUP BY language
HAVING COUNT(country) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but it's only listing one country for each common language, I am trying to list all of the countries that share a common language